# How to add an enumerate list to this tree diagram?

Tags: trees, forest

So I am trying to add a list of the form

1.

2.

3.

under each subject in this tree diagram:

[image]

My problem is not in making the list itself, but rather in typing under the subjects. I tried both `\newline` and `\\`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  grow'=south,
  l sep=2cm,
  child anchor=north,
  parent anchor=south,
  edge={->,>=latex}}
[
  [\textbf{Electromagnetic Theory},
  ]
  [\textbf{Circuit Theory}
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `parbox`

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  grow'=south,
  l sep=2cm,
  child anchor=north,
  parent anchor=south,
  edge={->,>=latex}}
[
  [\parbox{4.5cm}{{\bfseries Electromagnetic Theory}     
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item text 
  \item text
  \item text
  \end{enumerate}}
  ]
  [\parbox{3cm}{{\bfseries Circuit Theory}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item text 
  \item text
  \item text
  \end{enumerate}}
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Nodes in Forest trees are tabular environments when `align` is used with an argument such as `center`. This means that `align` can accept any tabular specification, including `p` columns. So it is not necessary to use an explicit `\parbox`.

Since we want the `p` column size to vary, the most convenient solution is to use a style (`list me` in the example below) which accepts the width required. `@{}` can be used to kill off the separation of columns, which isn't needed in addition to the spacing provided by Forest.

Adapting [salim bou's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326318/):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  list me/.style={%
    align={@{}p{#1}@{}}
  },
  for tree={
    grow'=south,
    l sep=2cm,
    child anchor=parent,
    parent anchor=children,
    edge={->,>=latex},
  }
  [
    [{\bfseries Electromagnetic Theory}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \end{enumerate}, list me=45mm
    ]
    [{\bfseries Circuit Theory}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item text
    \item text
    \item text
    \end{enumerate}, list me=30mm
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

produces a similar result more conveniently:

[image: tabular nodes in Forest]